# XmlWriter throws exeception by XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString (SetAttribute token -> invalid XML Doc)

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, xmlwriter

I try to create a XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ebooks count="494">
.....
<ebook absolute_path="J:\eBooks\Apress - Pro ASP.NET 4 in VB 2010, Third Edition.Sep.2010.ENG.pdf">
    <file>Apress - Pro ASP.NET 4 in VB 2010, Third Edition.Sep.2010.ENG.pdf</file>
    <size bytes="40176052">40Mb</size>
    <created datetime="25.12.2010 12:48:52">25.12.2010</created>
    <location>J:\eBooks</location>
</ebook>
<ebook absolute_path="J:\eBooks\Apress - Pro PHP and jQuery.Jun.2010.pdf">
    <file>Apress - Pro PHP and jQuery.Jun.2010.pdf</file>
    <size bytes="12523132">12.5Mb</size>
    <created datetime="10.07.2010 19:43:10">10.07.2010</created>
    <location>J:\eBooks</location>
  </ebook>
.....
</ebooks>
```

I wrote following VB.NET code to achieve that output, but I always get an exception about SetAttribute Token and unvalid XML document.

```
Dim xmlFileName As String = "J:\eBooks\report_" & DateAndTime.Now.ToShortDateString & ".xml"
Dim xmlSetting As XmlWriterSettings = New XmlWriterSettings()
xmlSetting.Indent = True
Dim xw As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(xmlFileName, xmlSetting)
...
...
dim singleFile as String
Dim myPdfFiles() as String = Directory.GetFiles(<path_to_dir>, <pdf_files>, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
Try
    xw.WriteStartDocument()
    xw.WriteStartElement("ebooks")
    xw.WriteAttributeString("count", myPdfFiles.Count.ToString)
    For Each singleFile In myPdfFiles
        Dim fi As New FileInfo(singleFile)
        With xw
            .WriteStartElement("ebook")
            .WriteAttributeString("absolute_path", fi.FullName.ToString)
            .WriteElementString("file", fi.Name.ToString)
            .WriteElementString("size", Math.Round(fi.Length / 1048576, 2) & "Mb")
            'Attribute BYTES for <size>....'
            .WriteAttributeString("bytes", fi.Length.ToString) '<- EXCEPTION!!!!'
            .WriteElementString("created", fi.CreationTime.ToShortDateString)
            'xw.WriteAttributeString("datetime", fi.CreationTime) <- would throw exception too'
            .WriteElementString("location", fi.DirectoryName)
            .WriteEndElement() '...close <ebook> element'
        End With
     Next
     xw.WriteEndElement() '..close <ebooks> element'
     xw.WriteEndDocument()
     xw.Flush()
     xw.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Message : " & ex.Message)
End Try
```

Any Ideas why I get an exception? How do I get the XML-output as above ?

Comment: @František Žiačik My VisualStudio is in german, so translation would look like:
"StartAttribute token status in the Content would result in an invalid XML document"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XmlWriter.WriteElementString` writes an element *and a value*. It's like using:

```
writer.WriteStartElement("name");
writer.WriteString("value");
writer.WriteEndElement();
```

In other words, it doesn't leave you *within* the element you create. So instead of this:

```
.WriteElementString("size", Math.Round(fi.Length / 1048576, 2) & "Mb")
.WriteAttributeString("bytes", fi.Length.ToString)
```

I think you want:

```
.WriteStartElement("size")
.WriteAttributeString("bytes", fi.Length.ToString)
.WriteString(Math.Round(fi.Length / 1048576, 2) & "Mb")
.WriteEndElement()
```

Personally though, I'd rather create the whole thing in memory using LINQ to XML, unless it's going to be too big. That's generally an easier API to work with.

Comment: Thank you for quick replay. I will try it out. 
I not really familiar with LINQ. Could you also show "the LINQ version"?

Comment: V-Light: LINQ to XML isn't really LINQ as such... it's just an XML API which plays nicely with LINQ. I'm not familiar enough with VB (and don't have enough time) to convert your whole example into it - but I strongly suggest you read some tutorials on it. Learning LINQ would be a good idea too :)